# Rails Error submitting partial via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have the following code in my controller:

File: app/controllers/photos_controller.rb

```
def show_snapshot_comments
    snapshot = Snapshot.find(params[:id])
    @photo = snapshot.photo
    comments = snapshot.comments.paginate :page => params[:page]
    @snapshot_comment = snapshot.comments.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
   end
```

The JavaScript (jQuery):
File: app/views/photos/show_snapshot_comments.js.erb

```
$j('#info').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial  => "snapshot_comments",
        :locals   => {:snapshot => snapshot, :comments => comments}) %>" );
```

show_snapshot_copmments is called from:
app/views/photos/show.html.erb

It doesn't appear to be working.

My error:

Rendering photos/show_snapshot_comments

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined local variable or method `snapshot' for #<ActionView::Base:0x2aaaaea473c8>) on line #2 of app/views/photos/show_snapshot_comments.js.erb:
1: $j('#info').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial  => "snapshot_comments",
2:         :locals   => {:snapshot => snapshot, :comments => comments}) %>" );

    app/views/photos/show_snapshot_comments.js.erb:2
    app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:227:in `show_snapshot_comments'
```

Any ideas what may be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass the local variables to the partial 'snapshot_comments". However this two local variables, snapshot and comments are not defined in current scope (in the view).

If you want to pass variables to views from controller you have to do the following:

```
def show_snapshot_comments
    @snapshot = Snapshot.find(params[:id])
    @photo = snapshot.photo
    @comments = snapshot.comments.paginate :page => params[:page]
    @snapshot_comment = snapshot.comments.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
   end

$j('#info').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial  => "snapshot_comments",
        :locals   => {:snapshot => @snapshot, :comments => @comments}) %>" );
```

Try the code above and see if it works. I just change the snapshot and comments to @snapshot and @comments.

Comment: had missed the comments bit ;)

Comment: I swear I just saw an animation of a horse with a balloon when up-voting your answer. gotta be something in the water...

Comment: o dear, is that because of April Fool's day=)

Comment: Thanks!! Everything worked, except I had to add @ to all instances of snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

snapshot is set as a local variable in controller, so the template doesn't see it. Set it as an instance variable:

```
@snapshot = Snapshot.find(params[:id])
```

then in the template:

```
:locals   => {:snapshot => @snapshot
```